# How to get user data from API to use in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need your advice about this!

I am building an app on a Node/Express server with MongoDB. Every object in DB has a unique ID called "fb_id" (it's a FB messenger chat bot).

I wrote an endpoint to retrieve the a user object with the id as a URL parameter:

```
  app.get("/usersdata/:id", (req,res)=>{
    db.collection(USERSCOLLECTION).findOne({"fb_id": req.params.id},(err,doc)=>{
      if(err){
        handleError(res,err.message,"failed to get user data");
      } else{
        res.status(200).json(doc);
      }
    });
  });

I am using React in the front-end and D3, planning to build a personal dashboard for every user. Here is my starting code:

/*global React*/
/*global ReactBootstrap*/
/*global ReactDOM*/

alert("hello world");

const App = React.createClass({
//parent component to render all elements and hold state
    getInititialState(){
        return{

        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function(){


    },

    render: function(){

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Chart Here</h1>  
                <p>Hello</p>
            </div>
        );

    }

});//App component

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

And my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script> 
    <!--Load React and D3 script here-->    
    <script type="text/babel" src="/js/dashboard.js"></script>
    <!--link custom css file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>My Dashboard</h1>
        <!--Initialise React app here-->
        <div id="app">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My question is how can I retrieve this user data from the usersdata/:id endpoint to use in my React App? I want to save it a state object and work with it. Maybe I should do something in componentDidMount? Can you pls share what's the best approach for this, thank you.

Comment: have you tried ANY client side code?

Comment: I tried using fetch in componentDidMount() but not sure yet how to get the :id from the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you to separate the Express API code and the React Code into two apss. After that to fetch data into your react application, is better to use `componentDidMount()` method using axios(`npm install axios`).

```
  componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('localhost_url/usersdata/:id')
        .then(response => {
           this.setState({ message_user : response.data })
        })
  }
```

And them use it to show your data whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, i did the same thing eventually but using fetch